# Table View Controller in storyboard with Class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, storyboard

I added a Table View Controller to my storyboard. Then i set the Class of the Table View Controller to my class `SubscriptionsTableViewController: UITableViewController`

Now i want to populate it with a cell i've made.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("subscriptionCell") as! SubscriptionsTableViewCell
return cell
```

This gives me Value of type `SubscriptionsTableViewController has no member dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`

How do i access the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier in TableViewController class? Shouldn't i be able to use self.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier since i've set the class in Storyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is **not** `UITableViewController` method. It is `UITableView` method

So, you need

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("subscriptionCell") as! SubscriptionsTableViewCell
```

Check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:) first.

Be sure to register `SubscriptionsTableViewCell` as cell class of your table view.

Comment: Also to add the "subscriptionCell" as Cell Identifier in storyboard